# How to make access the rest of the buttons in a handleClick function

Tags: reactjs

I am making a quiz app in React. When I click the button that has the right answer, the button turns green, which is quite straightforward to implement. When a user clicks on the wrong button, the button turns red, but **I also want the right answer button to turn green.**  To achieve this I would need access to the rest of the `button` elements

```
 const handleClick = async (isCorrect, e, arr) => {
        console.log(e);
        if (isCorrect) {
            setScore(score + 1)
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
            await delay(1500)
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = ''
        } else {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            await delay(1500)
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = ''
        }
}
```

```
const listOfAnswers = questions[questionNumber].possibleAnswers.map((q, i, arr) => {
        return (
            <Button                
                onClick={e => handleClick(q.isCorrect, e, arr)}
            >
                {q.answer}
            </Button>
        )
    })
```

In the `else` block there, I need to implement the logic to do this, but unsure how to do it. As you can see, to this function, I am passing the `arr` I am iterating over using `map`, but I dont think this will help me find the rest of the `button` elements. All I want is to be able to access the rest of the buttons, so that I can do something similar to `e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'`, to show the user which answer was correct.

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a state for correct and incorrect class and toggle class when needed.

```
const [className, setClassName] = useState({});

const handleClick = async (q, e, arr) => {
  const {isCorrect, answer} = q
  if (isCorrect) {
    setScore(score + 1);
  } 

  setClassName({
    [answer]: isCorrect ?'correct': "incorrect",
  });
  await delay(1500);
  setClassName({});
};

const listOfAnswers = questions[questionNumber].possibleAnswers.map(
  (q, i, arr) => {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(q, e, arr)}
        className={className[q.answer]}
      >
        {q.answer}
      </Button>
    );
  }
);

// Style
.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have implemented your solution, unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: @5ecured what error you are getting.

Comment: No error, it is just not displaying what I want. The correct /green answer does not show up when I press the wrong answer